# Unable to prevent reordering of columns using jqgrid. I want to disable in the library itself that would be a generic solution

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

As of now  i am using the jqgrid library. It is allowing me to reorder the columns with mouse drag and drop. I want to disable this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You use probably `sortable: true` option of jqGrid, which will be frequently misunderstood. You should remove the option or set `sortable: false`.

Comment: Tried doing that still facing the same issue :(

Comment: @KhawerKhan: You should provide the demo, which reproduce the problem. I recommend you to look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/5w5h2Lgw/27/, which use `sortable: true` and https://jsfiddle.net/5w5h2Lgw/28/ without `sortable: true`